# Copy-Item from USB Does Not Work as a Job

Tags: powershell, copy-item, powershell-jobs

I'm copying files to a USB utilizing the path of the USB (assuming one drive plugged in) rather than the drive letter. I need to do it this way since I'm using this to clone 52 USBs at once.

This is where the prefix for the path is found:

```
$usb = Get-Volume | where {$_.DriveType -eq "Removable" }
$usb.Path
```

Which when concatenated with the rest of the file name becomes something like:

```
\\?\Volume{df4d4042-9133-11e9-9a6b-48a472473e67}\RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg
```

When I call `Copy-Item` outside of a job everything works and copies properly. When I call `Copy-Item` within a PowerShell job it fails and complains about the path. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Can someone tell me why my function `copyFilesSync` works properly, while `copyFiles` doesn't work?

For simplicity, I have cut the script back to just the elements that reproduce this issue. There is no practical difference between `$filestoCopyJSON1` and `$filestoCopyJSON2`. Swapping the actual files doesn't make a difference. I just needed two file names so I could run the two functions back-to-back and they were not copying the same file:

```
$filestoCopyJSON1 = '[
    {
        "FromFile":  "C:\\dev\\VMware-player-12.1.1-3770994.exe",
        "ToFile":  "\\\\?\\Volume{df4d4042-9133-11e9-9a6b-48a472473e67}\\VMware-player-12.1.1-3770994.exe"
    }
]'

$filestoCopyJSON2 = '[
    {
        "FromFile":  "C:\\dev\\RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg",
        "ToFile":  "\\\\?\\Volume{df4d4042-9133-11e9-9a6b-48a472473e67}\\RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg"
    }
]'

function copyFiles($filestoCopy){
    Write-Host "Copying $($filestoCopy.Count)"
    $copyblock = {
        $copy = $args[0]
        Write-Host "$($copy.FromFile)" "$($copy.ToFile)"
        Copy-Item "$($copy.FromFile)" "$($copy.ToFile)"
        $resultHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "$($copy.ToFile)"
    }

    foreach ($filetoCopy in $filestoCopy) {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $copyblock -ArgumentList @($filetoCopy)
    }

    Write-Host "Waiting on copying..."
    Get-Job | Wait-Job
    Write-Host "Files Copied"
}

function copyFilesSync($filestoCopy){
    foreach ($filetoCopy in $filestoCopy) {
        Copy-Item "$($filetoCopy.FromFile)" "$($filetoCopy.ToFile)"
        $resultHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "$($filetoCopy.ToFile)"
    }
}

Remove-Job -Name *
Write-Host "Sync File Copy"

copyFilesSync -filestoCopy $(ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $filestoCopyJSON1)

Write-Host "Async File Copy"
copyFiles -filestoCopy $(ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $filestoCopyJSON2)
Receive-Job -Name *
```

This results in the following output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\dev\Test.ps1
Sync File Copy
Async File Copy
Copying 1

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
207    Job207          BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Waiting on copying...
207    Job207          BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
Files Copied
C:\dev\RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg \\?\Volume{df4d4042-9133-11e9-9a6b-48a472473e67}\RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg
Illegal characters in path.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

The first file from the `Copy-Item` that's not in a job completes successfully. The async `Copy-Item` run through the job fails with the errors as have been seen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Powershell Jobs or Copy-Item. I'm not really sure which. I was able to bypass this by utilizing Background Runspaces instead of Jobs. As a result the following async code runs just fine:

```
     function copyFiles($filestoCopy){
        Write-Host "Copying $($filestoCopy.Count)" 
        $copyblock = {
            $filestoCopy = $args[0]
            foreach($filetoCopy in $filestoCopy){
                Copy-Item "$($filetoCopy.FromFile)" "$($filetoCopy.ToFile)"
                $resultHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "$($filetoCopy.ToFile)"

                if($filetoCopy.FromFileHash -ne $resultHash.hash){
                    Write-Host "File $($copy.ToFile) Failed.. trying again" 
                    Copy-Item "$($filetoCopy.FromFile)" "$($filetoCopy.ToFile)"
                }    
            }
        }

        $newPowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($copyblock).AddArgument($filestoCopy)
        $job = $newPowerShell.BeginInvoke()


        Write-Host "Waiting on copying..." 
        While (-Not $job.IsCompleted) {}
        $result = $newPowerShell.EndInvoke($job)
        $newPowerShell.Dispose()
        Write-Host "Files Copied" 
    }
```